# Adding text to Scintilla without losing formatting

Tags: vb.net, scintilla

I'm starting development using scintilla in VB.NET and I'm creating a serial terminal program. The Scintilla control shows what data has been received in my computer serial port.

I need to programmatically add text to control.

When I use:

```
Scintilla1.Text = Scintilla1.text & "New Data received" & chr(13)
```

the text is added to Scintilla but it clears all formatting that exists in text that was in control before adding.

So, my questions:

1 - The way I'm adding text to Scintilla is correct? I did not found a method "AddText()".

2 - Why I'm losing text formatting when I add text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lose formatting as your assigning to `Scintilla1.Text` which will replace *everything (including any styling you've applied) in the window.

As you say `AddText` or `AppendText` are the ways to preserve whats already there.